# How do I use Read Replicas?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've read all the docs on the [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) site, and I now understand how to created and manage Read Replicas, but I have not seen any information about how to *use* them,

- Does Google automatically load-balance connections between all instances?
- Do I have to manually connect to a specific Read Replica to avoid hitting the Master?  If so, do I have to manage reconnecting on replica failure myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Does Google automatically load-balance connections between all instances?**

No, it doesn't. Each instance is independent. You can connect to replicas and use them to read while using the master to read/write, but you need to design that logic into your application

**Do I have to manually connect to a specific Read Replica to avoid hitting the Master? If so, do I have to manage reconnecting on replica failure myself?**

Yes, you have to connect to a specific read replica. Right now you can't even save and reuse the instance IP like you can do with compute engine instances (sigh, I hope they fix this soon....).

There is now a failover replica option that you can use so you don't need to connect to the read replica yourself, but it only activates on failure, it is not a load balancer.

Comment: Does it say this in the documentation, because i do not recall seeing anything about it ?

Comment: @IllegalOperator yes it does, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/tips): `Cloud SQL does not provide load balancing between replicas.`

Comment: So it just simplifies the process of copying data to another database?

Answer (score 4):

Read replica can be used by setting up [ProxySQL](http://proxysql.com/). You can configure ProxySQL to distribute the database queries. [Here is a community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/horizontally-scale-mysql-database-backend-with-google-cloud-sql-and-proxysql#configuring-proxysql-to-distribute-database-queries) providing more details on architecture and configuration example.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I use Read Replicas?

1. Use them for disaster recovery or to migrate your database to
   another region by promoting a read replica to become a primary
   database.
   https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/cross-region-replicas

2. Use them for separating read workloads from production workloads. This blog post covers using Read Replicas for analytics workloads:

- [Use Cloud SQL Read Replicas to separate your analytics and production workloads](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/use-cloud-sql-read-replicas-separate-your-analytics-and-production-workloads)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL does not provide load balancing between replicas[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZLfV.png)

ref:https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/replication