# Cloud SQL DB and Read Replica configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We need a read replica for our Cloud SQL database , but I have some confusion regarding the following:

How should we handle requests coming for both the main database IP and the read replica database? Do we need to include both IPs in our code (which I believe should be handled at the infrastructure level)?
Since multiple applications use the same database IP, how can we centralize this? Is it possible to map the IP to a domain and use it in all applications? Can we accomplish this with minimal configuration at the Cloud SQL end?

Comment: Have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/horizontally-scale-mysql-database-backend-with-google-cloud-sql-and-proxysql#configuring-proxysql-to-distribute-database-queries) and [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43769260/18265702).

Comment: You have to use Cloud SQL proxy. It's designed to abstract that complexity.